# Python script to calculate hypotenuse and angle measure based on user inputs and classes

Tags: python

So far, finding the hypotenuse, "side c" works fine without problems, the problem is when I try to calculate the angle, I am pretty sure it's returning a wrong value for the angle.

```
import math
from math import sqrt

class Triangle:

    def __init__(self, side_a, side_b, ):
        self.side_a = side_a
        self.side_b = side_b

    def SidesCalculate(self, ):
        side_c = sqrt(self.side_a ** 2 + self.side_b ** 2)
        return side_c

    def AnglesCalculate(self, side_c):
        x = math.sin(self.side_a / side_c)
        math.asin(x)
        x = round(x * 180 / math.pi)
        return x

g = Triangle(side_a=int(input("Enter side a: ")), side_b=int(input("Enter side b: ")))
print("side c =", + g.SidesCalculate())
print("angle is =", + g.AnglesCalculate(side_c=True), '°')
```

Comment: This looks weird `g.AnglesCalculate(side_c=True)`. Why do you input `True`, instead of the value of `side_c`?

Comment: Well, the value of c is supposed to be automatically inputted, if that's possible. The program is set to calculate side_c based on what the user inputs on side a and b. I was wondering if there was a way to make the program automatically get the value of from the SidesCalculate function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to do what you want.

First when you compute `side_c`, save it as an attribute.

```
def SidesCalculate(self, ):
    self.side_c = sqrt(self.side_a ** 2 + self.side_b ** 2)
    return self.side_c
```

Secondly, give the parameter `side_c` a default value `None`. (You also have another math error in the following function pointed by CFLS)

```
def AnglesCalculate(self, side_c = None):
    if side_c == None:
        side_c = self.side_c
    x = math.asin(self.side_a / side_c)
    x = round(x * 180 / math.pi)
    return x
```

Now, if you want the class to pick previously computed `side_c`, you can do this:

```
g = Triangle(side_a=int(input("Enter side a: ")), side_b=int(input("Enter side b: ")))
print("side c =", + g.SidesCalculate())
print("angle is =", + g.AnglesCalculate(), '°')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def AnglesCalculate(self, side_c):
    x = math.asin(self.side_a / side_c)
    x = round(x * 180 / math.pi)
    return x
```

Comment: This code returns an error,                                                             File "C:\Users\player\PycharmProjects\untitled5\Example.py", line 23, in <module>
    print("angle is =", + g.AnglesCalculate(side_c=True), '°')
  File "C:\Users\player\PycharmProjects\untitled5\Example.py", line 16, in AnglesCalculate
    x = math.asin(self.side_a / side_c)
ValueError: math domain error

Comment: While this code may solve the OP's issue, it is better to add context, or an explanation as to why this solves the OP's problem, so future visitors can learn from your post, and apply this knowledge to their own issues. High Quality Answers are much more likely to be upvoted, and contribute to the value and quality of SO as a platform. You can also add a link to documentation, if that helps.